# Introduction to supervised learning

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning

I have been asked to teach a module named ''Supervised Learning'', and the module is not well set up with precise topics or references. In a three month teaching period starting from 7th January 2022-7th March, there will be 3 hours of lectures in a week. Thus, could anyone help me set up the topics and possible references for the students from the syllabus outline below?

''This module will introduce the framework of supervised learning. Students will learn the framework of linear models and see examples of their extensions to generalized linear models. General modelling principles will be discussed, and students will learn the models of failure encountered when working with flexible, nonparametric models. Several modern nonparametric methods for regression and classification will be considered, and their performance evaluated on datasets from a variety of scientific problem domains. The emphasis throughout will be on principled, uncertainty-aware modelling.''

PS: I am a researcher in applied mathematics only but appointed as a lecturer in a college, I have never read Machine learning before. Thus it will be a learning process for me too along with the students.

Comment: Just look at the book on Machine Learning (Elements of Statistical Learning) by Hastie et al. I think it is used by several schools for teaching introductory/advanced machine learning.

Comment: Another idea would be to look at some popular online machine learning courses (for instance the one taught by Andrew Ng at Stanford) and then design the course based on the content taught in those courses.

Comment: Another good book to look at is An Introduction to Statistical Learning by James, Witten, Hastie, and Tibshirani.

Comment: @miosaki Questions like yours are likely better suited for the [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) SE site. Nonetheless, if you're not familiar with that site, I suggest first checking their [Help center](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/help) to determine the appropriateness of your question, how to best phrase it, etc., before possibly posting any questions there.

Comment: Thank you all...